# Universal Links redirection to specific view

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I'm having a hard time understanding how universal Link works.
First I have tried redirection to a specific UIViewController (Universal link works as it redirects the user from button click in email to my app) from the SceneDelegate but it ain't working.
I also noticed that the URL is not handled in appDelegate and I have no idea why.

Here is a snippet from the function in AppDelegate :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                     restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool
    {
       print("am I even here ?")
        
        guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
                let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL,
              
                let components = NSURLComponents(url: incomingURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
                return false
            }
            

            // Check for specific URL components that you need.
            guard let path = components.path,
            let params = components.queryItems else {
                return false
            }
           print("path = \(path)")

            if let userId = params.first(where: { $0.name == "_id" } )?.value,
                let token = params.first(where: { $0.name == "token" })?.value {
                print("_id = \(userId)")
                print("token = \(token)")
                return true

            } else {
                print("Either INDEX ARE MISSING")
                return false
            }

    }
```

Snippet from SceneDelegate :

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
           // the url is going to be in userActivity.webpageURL
        print(userActivity.webpageURL)
        print(userActivity.webpageURL?.pathComponents[2])
        print(userActivity.webpageURL?.pathComponents[1])
        
        if (userActivity.webpageURL?.lastPathComponent != nil ) {
            
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            let vc = self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController
            //queryVC?.urlQueryId = queryId!
            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)

        
          

            
            print("am I moving ?")

         
        }
    }
```

I am sorry in advance, I'm still new to swift and IOS in general and it feels like I am stuck in a loop.

ps: the data from SceneDelagate prints, I get both parameters and the full URL too with parameteres.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey this was fixed, starting ios 13 and if you have scene delegate, that's where you should handle the response.
This was how I fixed it.

```
if (userActivity.webpageURL?.pathComponents[2] != nil)
        {
           
            let userId = userActivity.webpageURL?.pathComponents[1]
            let token = userActivity.webpageURL?.pathComponents[2]
           
            
             if self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController != nil {
                 self.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                    }

            let Main =  self.window?.rootViewController?.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResetPassword") as? ResetPasswordViewController
            
            //Main.userIdentification = "fd"
            Main?.userIdFromUrl = userId
            Main?.UsertokenFromUrl = token
           // Main.userToken = "aa"
            
            Main?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(Main!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
            
        }
        else {print("doesn't contain")}
```

userIdFromUrl and UsertokenFromUrl are too variables I initialized in my target view Controller.
I hope this helps anyone. There were few tutorials mentioning the use of scene delegate and after reading through a dozen, I was eventually running around in cirlces.

You can also read more about it :

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-universal-links-in-your-app